# How can I wait for an input while something else happens at the same time?

Tags: python, while-loop, break, text-based

I've been having a really hard time putting this problem into words. What I'm trying to do is to have a while-loop constantly running, unless I give a 'stop' command.

I'm making a fishing mini-game in a bigger game, and I want to be able to start fishing on command (which I have been able to do), and for the fishing to continue happening, until I eventually type 'stop'.

The way I've been doing things is that I ask for a command input, then do something based on the command. However, in this situation, I dont want to do that, because asking for the input pauses the while-loop.

I'm open to other suggestions on how to exit the while-loop with a certain command, but the game is text-based, so ideally I want a text command to exit.

```
if command == 'fish':
    print('You start fishing')
    while True:
        # fishing happens, you may or may not catch something
        # if you enter a command ('exit'), you stop fishing
        # I dont, however, want the code to pause to ask for a command.
        # I want it to be uninterrupted fishing, until I choose to exit
```

Comment: Can you share your code so we can help you better? Without it its kinda hard to see what you exactly are trying to do.

Comment: There, I felt like adding code was hard, as I'm not really sure how I would even go about it

Comment: Do you still need an answer to this?

Comment: @FrozenAra yes please, if you have one :) I've just formattet it in a way that asks me to say if I'd like to continue after a certain time interval atm

Comment: Ill try to thing of something. Ill come back to this when I got something!

Answer (score 1):

you need 2 `loops` here and `flags` , when user `pauses` the `pauseFlag` become `True` and your code will come out from the `inner loop` and when he `unpause` the `pauseFlag` switches to `False` and Code will enter the `inner loop` again and the game will resuming.

Somthing like below:

```
while(quitFlag):
    while(!pauseFlag):
        #your code
        if(somthing):
            pauseFlag = True

   if(somthing):
      pauseFlag = False # and it make the code goes to the second loop again and resume the game
```

Maybe you wonder : what is `quitFlag` ? as you see it's the condition of the first loop. Whenever `quitFlag` switches to `false` the game will shut down and The user can't resume the game and he must start the game all over.

Comment: With this code, will I be able to start fishing, then the game will keep fishing until I choose to type in a command ('exit')?

Comment: @glennrv I didn't get your question, but this type of code is so flexible for these textUI games.

Comment: The way I understand it, with your code, I will have pauses in the loop, in which I will be asked for a command. I want to not have this pause at all.